# Is Infra Red light safe to use on your scalp?

Tags: blood-circulation, hair

I own an Anodyne Infrared therapy device which I use to treat ligament/tendon/muscular pains and it works nicely.

[image: http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00V0WMARS]

I see other infrared products used to combat hair loss (e.g. [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01B29PCUU](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01B29PCUU)), but I don't know the nuances of different infrared devices. Is it safe to use the device intended for the above uses on my scalp? I'd rather not purchase a separate infrared device for my scalp if I own the necessary technology already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are entirely different devices. First off, the Anodyne product is truly far-infrared, emitting at 890 nm (infrared is above ~650-700 nm). However, the hair loss product you linked is far-red/near-infrared, with laser diodes emitting at 650 nm (which is why it glows red). If you put the Anodyne product on your skull, you'd just heat up your brain, possibly burning any hair you have left. (Well, maybe not, but it sounds kind of funny.)

I would strongly suggest you don't try regrowing your hair using an instrument designed to relax your muscles. I will give you a recommendation - read the small print *very* carefully. The hair product is only recommended for a certain type of hair loss called Androgenetic Alopecia. Please consult with your doctor to determine if you actually have this condition, otherwise your investment of US$600-700 will be completely wasted.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you for the insight. Looking at this pic, I probably do have Androgenetic Alpoecia but like you say it's worth checking if this is true before I get my hopes up and spend effort (more burdensome than the money!).